# How do I open a specific google sheet by index location using google script

Tags: java, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, google-apps

I want to create 2 buttons to allow users to scroll backwards and forwards through the sheets in a google spreadsheet. I'm new to Java and google apps and my pea-brain can't work it out. Here's the code I have. Any corrections / suggestions welcome as it doesn't currently work properly.

```
function nextSheet (){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getIndex();
  var num = sheet +1;
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[num]);

}

function prevSheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var num = (sheet.getIndex())-1;
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[num]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function nextSheet (){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getIndex();
  var num = sheet +1;
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[num-1]);

}
```

getIndex() is 1-based (starts from 1), but arrays are 0 based. This is the problem. Change [num] to [num-1] as I have done above and it will work.